# How to use sortedByDescending in a Kotlin stream?

Tags: kotlin, generics, stream

I am trying to put together a streaming solution in Kotlin that will

1. Read in lines from standard input representing player teams, names, games, and points
2. Filter out the players that have been in 15 games or more
3. Sort the players by points-per-game descending
4. Print the top ten such players.

In Java, I was able to do this in a "single" stream

```java
    // JAVA SOLUTION - WORKS
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        .lines()
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(Player::fromLine)
        .filter(p -> p.games >= 15)
        .sorted((p1, p2) -> Double.compare(p2.ppg, p1.ppg))
        .limit(10)
        .map(Player::reportLine)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In the Java code above, I made a `Player` record whose `fromLine` static method does the string-to-number conversion and creates a player record with the points-per-game computed in the `ppg` field.

However, I am not able to translate this into Kotlin so directly. I tried:

```kotlin
// KOTLIN ATTEMPT - THIS DOES NOT WORK
BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.`in`))
    .lines()
    .map { it.split(",") }
    .map { Player.fromLine(it) }
    .filter { it.games >= 15 }
    .sortedByDescending { it.ppg }  // ERROR ON THIS LINE
    .take(10)
    .map { it.reportLine() }
    .forEach { println(it) }
```

The error is (not surprisingly)

> error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:  ...

I take it this is because `sortedByDescending` wants its receiver to be an array or an iterable (which I know from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html)). I have solved this problem and got my code to work by doing things in two steps:

```kotlin
// KOTLIN SOLUTION - WORKS (but can it done in one shot?)
val players = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.`in`))
    .lines()
    .map { it.split(",") }
    .map { Player.fromLine(it) }
    .filter { it.games >= 15 }
    .toList()

players.sortedByDescending { it.ppg }
    .take(10)
    .map { it.reportLine() }
    .forEach { println(it) }
```

Is there any way to get the sort "into a single stream"?

And I guess a deeper question might be why is the result of the `filter` call, right before the `sortedByDescending` call in the non-working solution, not producing an proper iterable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if you planned to use `Stream` from the Java stdlib or `Sequence` from the Kotlin stdlib. Operators you use (`take()`, `sortedByDescending()`) are typical for Kotlin, but you use exactly the same `.lines()` function as in Java, so it returns the API typical for Java (`Stream`).

To fix the problem you need to either stick to Java API, so use `sorted()` and `limit()` as in your Java code. Or you need to stick to Kotlin API, so use `lineSequence()` instead of `lines()`.

Comment: Very helpful - thanks for the push to go all-in on Kotlin. I did not know about `lineSequence`, and it worked great.  Taking your sticking to the Kotlin API suggestion, I looked more deeply into Kotlin sequences and found that kicking the whole thing off with `generateSequence { readLine() }.map ...` made the whole lines thing unnecessary and allowed me to get right of the weird Java imports for BufferedReader, etc.